# "The tenure-track professor plans to carry out X publications." So, what could X be here?

Tags: computer-science, professorship, tenure-track, contract

I signed a contract for a 6-year tenure-track professorship in a European University a few weeks ago.

Recently, I received an Agreement document between me and the University, whose main objective is to specify the details of my research and my teaching at the University.

Most of the information to fill out makes sense, except the one that is about *the number of publications that I plan to produce*. I am not sure what to put here, and whether this will start some kind of negotiation with the University.

Even if I am urged to put a high number, I could opt to publish to just about any low-rank venue (which I would not like).

Being completely honest, if I were to set expectations for myself, it would not be in the form of a number. I tend to do good research and the publications come as a consequence of this attitude, but this number has never been a metric that I targeted.

Perhaps entering a low conservative value would be the best approach?

Comment: I think this really needs advice from someone who is familiar with the local context. Can you talk to other people who have gone through the tenure process and/or your head of department/similar?

Comment: I feel so strongly about avid's comment that I'm voting to close (for strongly depending on individual factors).

Comment: @avid ok, so I did some research, and I saw that the law stipulates that this agreement should "specify the objectives of research", and apparently someone from the administration thought that using numbers would be a good way to do it. I told the university that perhaps a descriptive text is better there, and will wait for their response.

Comment: *Being completely honest, if I were to set expectations for myself* You are a professor, these are the publications of your group, there is not anymore a "me", now you are "my research group". Getting a professorship is a big change, especially because your failure is "my research group failure". 
If you are an asshole you take it as a way out, if you are a decent person you will read it as a"my research group failure is my falilure" ... it is up to you, enjoy the responsibility :D .
A part from this detail, I share your fundamental doubt about giving any value to the number of publications.

Comment: @EarlGrey Yes, I agree with you. In fact, your comment helped me realize that the Agreement itself is mostly structured around me as an individual. To be fair, this is a new way of recruiting professors for the Uni, so probably the Uni hasn't had time to iron out some flaws with the documentation. I am still waiting for their response. I could have put a value of 30 there and impress them, and then just publish everything on arXiv, and I would have met the publication "goal" :P

Comment: Eh, at least a local system would not allow that for a number of reasons. Putting aside a chunk of grant money just to pay APCs in Frontiers is fair game though, perverse incentives all the way. Bear in mind that this is likely to be a financial decision for the university - if you and your group only produce one paper in two years, this means bad metrics and loss of funding, if you claim five papers a year when the reasonable expectation would be two, the university would question such an application. Low (but not too low) conservative value is good.

Comment: I'm going to hammer this one closed (it had three close votes two years ago, not counting me). The dilemma is interesting, but Europe is a big place, and this doesn't even specify a field, so we couldn't possibly give better advice than you could give yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that people could publish any number of articles if quality of the work and the journal are not a concern. I would put a number that seems like a reasonable estimate of the number of high quality papers you are likely to publish during that time frame. So maybe somewhere between 2 and 5 per year, depending on the field? In some fields, studies can take years to complete, so there will be many fewer completed and published than in a field in which studies can be completed in a few weeks or months.

Comment: Depends a lot on the field and subfield. Two per year is a lot in math and many highly theoretical subjects, including parts of CS.